# Andoid Studio WebView. Создать новый Intent по нажатию на определенную кнопку

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

При помощи WebView отображаю сайт, url которого начинается с "https://example/register/"

Код в Android Studio:

```java
@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("https://example/register/")){
                    currentURL = url;
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Мне необходимо, что бы ***при нажатии на кнопку отправки формы***, эта же страница открылась в браузере, естественно, url.startsWith не позволяет этого сделать.

Код в HTML-файле сайта:

```
<form action="https://example/register" method="post" target="_blank">
        <div style="display:none">
            <textarea id="Login" autocomplete="off" name="code"><?=$_SESSION['user']['code'] ?></textarea>
            <textarea id="Pass"  autocomplete="off" name="pass"><?=$_SESSION['user']['pass'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Перейти">
            </center>
        </form>
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: А в чём цель затеи? Вы в курсе, что ни сессия, ни данные формы в браузер не попадут при переходе?

Comment: Цель затеи в том, что на странице содержится <input type="file">, перепробовал множество способов чтобы оживить его внутри webView, по-этому было решено добавить кнопку с переходом на эту же страницу но в браузере.

Comment: Ну и задали бы вопрос по теме. А так юзеру придётся логиниться и в приложении, и в браузере. Про отправку файла здесь был вопрос, не пробовали поискать?